# Cubo mágico en SQL, MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Trato de hacer un query que muestre un cubo mágico de 3x3, en el cuál al sumar los números de cada casilla, tanto horizontal, vertical y en ambas diagonales de 15 de resultado, esto a partir de una tabla con un solo campo llamado id y teniendo los valores {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}.

La idea es que quede algo como:

```
492
357
816
```

De momento llevo el código que presento a continuación, pero no logro hacerlo de 3x3, me hago un poco bolas, ojala pudieran orientarme con este problema, gracias de antemano.

```
SELECT n1.id , n2.id , n3.id , n4.id , n5.id , n6.id ,n7.id ,n8.id , n9.id

FROM tarea1 n1, tarea1 n2,tarea1 n3,tarea1 n4,tarea1 n5,tarea1 n6,tarea1 n7,tarea1 n8,tarea1 n9

WHERE (n1.id+n2.id+n3.id=15 AND n4.id+n5.id+n6.id=15 AND n7.id+n8.id+n9.id=15 AND n1.id+n4.id+n7.id=15 AND n3.id+n6.id+n9.id=15 AND n1.id+n5.id+n9.id=15 AND n3.id+n5.id+n7.id=15 
AND n1.id<>n2.id AND n1.id<>n3.id AND n1.id<>n4.id AND n1.id<>n5.id AND n1.id<>n6.id AND n1.id<>n7.id AND n1.id<>n8.id AND n1.id<>n9.id AND n2.id<>n1.id AND n2.id<>n3.id AND n2.id<>n4.id AND n2.id<>n5.id AND n2.id<>n6.id AND n2.id<>n7.id AND n2.id<>n8.id AND n2.id<>n9.id  
AND n3.id<>n1.id AND n3.id<>n2.id AND n3.id<>n4.id AND  n3.id<>n5.id AND n3.id<>n6.id AND n3.id<>n7.id AND n3.id<>n8.id AND n3.id<>n9.id 
AND n4.id<>n1.id AND n4.id<>n2.id AND n4.id<>n3.id AND n4.id<>n5.id AND n4.id<>n6.id AND n4.id<>n7.id AND n4.id<>n8.id AND n4.id<>n9.id 
AND n5.id<>n1.id AND n5.id<>n2.id AND n5.id<>n3.id AND n5.id<>n4.id AND n5.id<>n6.id AND  n5.id<>n7.id AND n5.id<>n8.id AND n5.id<>n9.id 
AND n6.id<>n1.id AND n6.id<>n2.id AND n6.id<>n3.id AND n6.id<>n4.id AND n6.id<>n5.id AND n6.id<>n7.id AND n6.id<>n8.id AND n6.id<>n9.id 
AND n7.id<>n1.id AND n7.id<>n2.id AND n7.id<>n3.id AND n7.id<>n4.id AND n7.id<>n5.id AND n7.id<>n6.id AND n7.id<>n8.id AND n7.id<>n9.id 
AND n8.id<>n1.id AND n8.id<>n2.id AND n8.id<>n3.id AND n8.id<>n4.id AND n8.id<>n5.id AND n8.id<>n6.id AND n8.id<>n7.id AND n8.id<>n9.id
AND n9.id<>n1.id AND n9.id<>n2.id AND n9.id<>n3.id AND n9.id<>n4.id AND n9.id<>n5.id AND n9.id<>n6.id AND n9.id<>n7.id AND n9.id<>n8.id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hola te brindo una ayuda en cuanto a limitar los resultados, espero que te sirva de algo:

```
SELECT n1.id , n2.id , n3.id

FROM tarea1 n1, tarea1 n2,tarea1 n3,tarea1 n4,tarea1 n5,tarea1 n6,tarea1 n7,tarea1 n8,tarea1 n9

WHERE (n1.id+n2.id+n3.id=15 AND n4.id+n5.id+n6.id=15 AND n7.id+n8.id+n9.id=15 AND n1.id+n4.id+n7.id=15 AND n3.id+n6.id+n9.id=15 AND n1.id+n5.id+n9.id=15 AND n3.id+n5.id+n7.id=15 
AND n1.id<>n2.id AND n1.id<>n3.id AND n1.id<>n4.id AND n1.id<>n5.id AND n1.id<>n6.id AND n1.id<>n7.id AND n1.id<>n8.id AND n1.id<>n9.id AND n2.id<>n1.id AND n2.id<>n3.id AND n2.id<>n4.id AND n2.id<>n5.id AND n2.id<>n6.id AND n2.id<>n7.id AND n2.id<>n8.id AND n2.id<>n9.id  
AND n3.id<>n1.id AND n3.id<>n2.id AND n3.id<>n4.id AND  n3.id<>n5.id AND n3.id<>n6.id AND n3.id<>n7.id AND n3.id<>n8.id AND n3.id<>n9.id 
AND n4.id<>n1.id AND n4.id<>n2.id AND n4.id<>n3.id AND n4.id<>n5.id AND n4.id<>n6.id AND n4.id<>n7.id AND n4.id<>n8.id AND n4.id<>n9.id 
AND n5.id<>n1.id AND n5.id<>n2.id AND n5.id<>n3.id AND n5.id<>n4.id AND n5.id<>n6.id AND  n5.id<>n7.id AND n5.id<>n8.id AND n5.id<>n9.id 
AND n6.id<>n1.id AND n6.id<>n2.id AND n6.id<>n3.id AND n6.id<>n4.id AND n6.id<>n5.id AND n6.id<>n7.id AND n6.id<>n8.id AND n6.id<>n9.id 
AND n7.id<>n1.id AND n7.id<>n2.id AND n7.id<>n3.id AND n7.id<>n4.id AND n7.id<>n5.id AND n7.id<>n6.id AND n7.id<>n8.id AND n7.id<>n9.id 
AND n8.id<>n1.id AND n8.id<>n2.id AND n8.id<>n3.id AND n8.id<>n4.id AND n8.id<>n5.id AND n8.id<>n6.id AND n8.id<>n7.id AND n8.id<>n9.id
AND n9.id<>n1.id AND n9.id<>n2.id AND n9.id<>n3.id AND n9.id<>n4.id AND n9.id<>n5.id AND n9.id<>n6.id AND n9.id<>n7.id AND n9.id<>n8.id) LIMIT 3;
```

Con la consulta anterior te quedan una simulación de 3 x 3.
En realidad limitas, a 3 columnas con un máximo de 3 resultados establecido por el LIMIT 3, esto es en MySQL no ? Cada lenguaje de SQL maneja distinto el LIMIT.
La parte del algoritmo no lo revise tanto en detalle.
Es un ejercicio interesante, aunque desconozco porque en SQL jaja.
También podrías utilizar Transact-SQL es decir funciones, o procedimientos almacenados.
Saludos.